# Is there a way to list all my questions that have not been marked as accepted yet?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I'd like to show the list of my own questions which don't have accepted yet.

Is it possible?

Comment: [user:me hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A365251+hasaccepted%3A0&mixed=0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3A0+deleted%3Aall&mixed=0 (as you are 10k+)

Comment: There isn't any fancy link? Won't remember that sintax the next year :)

Comment: get back to meta next year ;)

Comment: You mean the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) then?